# LTspice create a model with <InstName> attribute as a variable

Tags: ltspice, spice, model

Don't know if my title was correctly put. Here is what I want.
I am creating a new module. Each time I add new module I get on top of the module `X1`, `X2`,etc as I add more and more. Now I want it to display it `M1`,`M2`, etc as I add one after the other.

Second is, I want to use this number displayed on each added model as variable inside the module. Meaning, inside the Model named `M1`, I want to multiply `M1*I`. In the main circuit I will defin `.param M1 = 0.2` Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: +1 for the hilarious sketch.  Reminds me of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTq7z.png).  You know MSPaint has circles, rectangles, and text boxes...right?  Can also take screenshots of your LTspice window to better get the point across.

Comment: @SteKulov I am laughing out of my chair. You are spot on and correct. It looks like a kid painting. I just thought of drawing like a pencil. I will use them. Thanks

Comment: Haha.  No worries.  Looks great now!

Answer (score 1):

The reference designators (e.g. `R1`, `L13`, `J007`, etc) can be renamed to whatever name you like, as long as they are *unique* and you're within the GUI. That's because LTspice (and all SPICEs that allow this) will prevent you from shooting in the foot by prepending an `X` to the newly created ref. des. in the netlist (Menu > *View > SPICE Netlist*). That `X` means the netlist entry is a subcircuit. Any other letter will mean something else than a subcircuit.

So, if you have a subcircuit and its instance is `U1`, the netlist will show:

```
XU1 ...
```

If you then rename it to `M1`, then you will see `M1` in the schematic, but the netlist will show:

```
XM1 ...
```

For the second part of your question, do you mean that the `I` in `M1*I` is a current (from the schematic, somewhere), or a `.param`?

If it's the first, just forget it. All ref. des. must be known prior to simulation start and, after the simulation has started, they stay fixed. And that makes perfect sense: the solver will need to solve for the currents, and if the current at `time=0` is for `Ix(U1:A)`, but at `time=1u` the name changes, it will fail. No SPICE will alow you to do that.

If it's the second, well, you *could* have something similar, but **not** with letters, and certainly not with reference designators, but with names, instead. You still can't use currents, since the names must stay unchanged, for (I would think, by now) obvious reasons.

To be sure we're on the same wavelength, the name is the default value `R` when you place a resistor, or the `V` when placing a voltage source, or the `SW` when placing a voltage controlled switch, etc. These are the default values, but for a subcircuit they can be names. This is a quick example:

[image: number as name, nor ref.des.]

I've used the symbol for resistor to call a subcircuit. The reference designator has been renamed from `R1` to `whatever1`, and you can see the netlist entry has an `X` at the beginning -- if it didn't, the next first letter would have been `W` which would have been interpreted as a current controlled switch (`CSW`). The name, however, was written as `{X}`. The usage of curly braces signals the engine to perform an evaluation and, since all `.param` and `.step` evaluations are performed brefore the simulation, `X` will evaluate to one of the two numeric literals in the `.step` command: `100` or `200`. These two are also the names of the two subcircuits you see defined below. This means that the `.step` command will first use `100` for the value of `X`, the name of the `whatever1` symbol will evaluate to the value of `x`, `100`, which will cause the subcircuit named `100` to be called. The next `.step` will make `X` evaluate to `200` so `.subckt 200` will be called.

As you can see, it works, and the current through the subcircuit is plotted. If the reference designator would have been changed, plotting would not have been possible.

Comment: My apologies for not having to communicate clearly. Now I have edited my question and my plot. This clearly states what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @Mainland It's a bit clearer, but what I said remains: you can't touch the reference designators with anything else but alpha-numeric characters, never `.param` or `.func` values. I also suspect this to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/#), so it would help if you stated what is your *purpose*, as opposed to what you *think* you need to do [in order to get to the not mentioned purpose]. Because there may be different solutions.